# find with reactive mongo and play framework

Tags: scala, playframework, play-reactivemongo

I want to retrieve a user's data by his mail from MongoDB using ReactiveMongo driver for play framework but it returns: `Future(<not completed>)`

Here is my code:

```scala
def findBymail(email: String) = {
  val query = Json.obj("mail" -> email)
  val resul = collection.flatMap(_.find(query).one[Users])
  Logger.warn(s"result found: $res") 
}
```

Comment: Actually, your `findBymail` returns `Unit`, rather than returning the `find` result, which is a `Future[Option[Users]]` (as intended for async query)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All operations in ReactiveMongo is async, it always returns `Future`, So you can print the result with

```
collection.flatMap(_.find(query).one[Users]).map{ u => Logger.warn(s"result found: $res")
```

I think this may not you want, you can return the `Future` as well, and handle the result,

```
def findBymail(email: String) = {
  val query = Json.obj("mail" -> email)
  collection.flatMap(_.find(query).one[Users]).map{ user =>
      Logger.warn(s"result found: $user") 
      user
  }
}
```

You can handle the result as:

```
findBymail("....").map{ user =>
    ......
}
```

Comment: thanks ,it works but i don't understand why you used the .map methode with the flatmap.I thought that .flatMap methode will handel it

Comment: collection is a Future[Collection], in here  collection.flatMap will return a Future[User],

Comment: because _find.... returns a Future[User], the flatMap will flat Future[Future[User]] to Future[User], that is why I can use map after flatMap